# Ionic 2 - Ripple effect manually

Tags: ionic2

I want to add a ripple effect to the header of a card, because it is touchable. I don't want to make it a button, though, because

- The CSS would get a bit weird, as I want to do some custom things with it
- It doesn't really represent the semantics of what it is.

So, my question is, I'm creating a directive for this sort of thing. How do I manually add the ripple effect on click/tap for it?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add ripple effect to an ionic 2 element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38748894/how-to-add-ripple-effect-to-an-ionic-2-element)

Answer (score 1):

You can install `ionic-ripple` and attach it to whatever element you want to have the effect on

https://github.com/DarrylD/ionic-ripple

Comment: This is for Ionic 1, as is seen in the README. However, I'll test it out when I have time. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

after reading the source code of ionic 2, i find that you can add the 'tappable' attribute to the DOM that you want to have the effect, then append the element `<div class="button-effect"></div>` as the child node of the target DOM. make sure your target DOM have the style `position: relative;overflow: hidden;`. 
[the above method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qssw1.png)

the another method is add the two `ion-button clear` attribute to the target DOM. this way also have to modify the style.

[the image show the element can get the given "active" style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/swx04.png)