# How to add ripple effect to an ionic 2 element?

Tags: material-design, ionic2

Some elements, like the button, have native ripple effect on Ionic 2. Others like cards doesn't. How could I add support to ripple effect on an arbitrary Ionic 2 element?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try wrapping the content like this:

```
<button ion-item>
   <ion-item style="background: rgba(0,0,0,0);">Content</ion-item>
</button>
```

Comment: Works perfectly, but no need for the inner ion-item

Answer (score 6):

As I see by sources of Ionic v3.3, a container element must contain an empty `div` element with `button-effect` class, also the container must have `tappable` attribute and be styled as `position: relative; overflow: hidden`.

In my project I use a following directive to style button-like containers:

```
import {Directive, ElementRef, Host, Renderer2} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[m-ripple-effect]',
    host: {
        'tappable': '',
        'role': 'button',
        'style': 'position: relative; overflow: hidden'
    }
})
export class RippleEffectDirective {
    constructor(@Host() host: ElementRef, renderer: Renderer2) {
        const div = renderer.createElement('div');
        renderer.addClass(div, 'button-effect');
        renderer.appendChild(host.nativeElement, div);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this gem. I have been trying to change the color of the ripple, the working solution I have is a css rule .button-effect{background-color: #FFF}. How can I put this in the directive?

Comment: A directive can't have a template or a style. You should add this rule to a css/scss file with global css styles. It may be 'src/theme/variables.scss' if you follow Ionic's project structure.

Comment: Please also check an updated version of the directive which runs on Ionic 3.9.2 here: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-ripple-effect-manually/52519/19

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the `button` element
and you can still have the ion-item directive:

From:

```
<ion-item (click)="viewArticle()"></ion-item>
```

To:

```
<button ion-item (click)="viewArticle()"></button>
```

Comment: Buttons breaks content formatting. For example, content with multiple lines will be inline.

Comment: @Natanael what if you add "text-wrap" to the button?

<button ion-item text-wrap ...></button>

Comment: it affect child content. when multiple click event inside in ion item.

Answer (score 1):

A more complete example based on the answer of Bartosz Kosarzycki:

```
                <ion-list>
                      <button ion-button style="height: auto!important;width: 100%" clear >
                            <ion-item style="background: rgba(0,0,0,0);">
                                  <ion-icon name="car" item-left></ion-icon>
                                  <h1>Title 1</h1>
                                  <p>Subtítulo</p>
                                  <ion-icon name="person" item-right></ion-icon>
                            </ion-item>
                      </button>
                      <button ion-button style="height: auto!important;width: 100%" clear>
                            <ion-item style="background: rgba(0,0,0,0);">
                                  <ion-icon name="person" item-left></ion-icon>
                                  <h1>Title 2</h1>
                                  <p>Subtítulo</p>
                                  <ion-icon name="car" item-right></ion-icon>
                            </ion-item>
                      </button>
                </ion-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

For IONIC 4 you can now use like this:

Make sure you div position is relative.

```
 <div
  ion-activatable
  class="ion-activatable"
  style="position:relative;height:100px;width:100%;background:blue;">
  <ion-ripple-effect></ion-ripple-effect>
  Content here...
</div>
```

:)